# Breaking RESTful design or getting two tables in one JSON object

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, rest

I'm developing a WCF RESTful web service with C# and .NET Framework 4.0. There is also a SQL Server database and I'm using Entity Framework Code First to access it.

I have these two tables on SQL Server:

A user table for my application's user.

```
User
{
   userId,
   name,
   country
}
```

And another table to store their thoughts about something.

```
Thought
{
   thoughtId,
   userId,
   description,
   date
}
```

Now, I want to show on an iPhone a `UITableView` these thoughts ordered by date. The `UITableViewCell` will be something like this:

```
User.name
Thought.description
Thought.date
```

**Can I return a JSON object this way?** (mixing columns from `user` and `thought` tables).

```
{
    "thoughtId": "1",
    "userId": "12",
    "name": "John",
    "description": "I'm thinking about you",
    "date": "12/12/2012"
}
```

Or, **what is it the best way to get this in one GET invoke?**

And finally, what will be its URI? `http://myhost/users/...` or `http://myhost/thoughts/...`

I have read somewhere that if I use `http://myhost/users/...`, I can only return `user` entities.

Comment: You can do that by creating a class ,say `UIViewDTO`, where DTO stands for data transfer object. This class will contain all those required properties which are thoughtId,userId,name,description,date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing non-RESTful about returning a composite entity as a resource - as long as the behaviour of that resource is RESTfully consistent. For example, you could fully-expand the `user` inside your `thought` entity if you chose to - though you have a potential conflict here in that you probably don't want users to try to *change* properties of a `user` when they're submitting edits to a `thought`.

Alternatively, you could expose an expanded entity through a different resource collection entirely (for argument's sake `http://myhost/thoughtview`), which could be a read-only collection of resources.  If you choose this route then it's worth exposing the canonical Uri of the `user` and the `thought` so that a client can easily edit the source objects, if required.

Remember, when you're designing your REST API, that the structure of the entities returned by your services doesn't have to match the structure of the data that you're storing behind the scenes. Make sure your service makes sense *at an API level*, and don't design your service around the way you think the data needs to be stored behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you have a one to many relationship between User and Thoughts.

So here is a LINQ query that will get you an object that represents what you want:

```
var query = User.Join
    (
        Thought,
        x=>x.userId,
        x.userId,
        (u,t)=>new 
        {
            t.thoughtId,
            u.userId,
            u.name,
            t.description,
            t.date
        }
    )
```

Then you can use something like [Newtonsoft JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) available as a Nuget package to turn this anonymous class in a JSon object.

An example would be :

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);
```

Now the string json is your array of objects.